NumberFormatter::getSymbol returns old symbol after the currency has been changed
I encountered unexpected behaviour of NumberFormatter class on one machine (Debian 10, php 8.3). Whereas on two other machines (Ubuntu 22.04, php 8.3) it works as expected.
When I create NumberFormatter object and change the currency with NumberFormatter::setTextAttribute method, the NumberFormatter::getSymbol method returns old currency symbol.
I create NumberFormatter object with specific locale:
$currencyFormatter = new NumberFormatter('hy_AM', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

Then I change currency:
$currencyFormatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE, 'USD');

Then I get currency symbol:
$symbol = $currencyFormatter->getSymbol(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_SYMBOL);

I'm expecting $ symbol but I'm getting ֏ symbol.
(NumberFormatter::format method works well and returns number with $ symbol)

I'm guessing you either have to use setSymbol and getSymbol in combination, or setTextAttribute and getTextAttribute ...?

I think you cannot change the locale. There's a good reason for that: An Armenian Dram isn't the same as an US Dollar. So changing the symbol would require the amount to change. That's not what NumberFormatter was made for. To use two different locales you need to create two different NumberFormatter objects.
